# Recursively passing in array address as argument

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, recursion

I have a function that will take in a buffer and a size, and copy that buffer (buffer A) into a larger buffer (buffer b). If the current size of buffer B plus the size of buffer A is too big, we split up buffer A for some to go in the current buffer B, and the rest to be inserted after we process our full buffer b.

Like so:

```
#define MAX_SIZE 1400
int WriteIndex = 0;
u8 buffer_b[2500];

void AddToBuffer(u8 buffer_a[], u16 bufferSize) {

    if ((WriteIndex + bufferSize) <= MAX_SIZE) {
        memcpy(&(buffer_b[WriteIndex]), &buffer_a, bufferSize);
        WriteIndex += bufferSize;
    } else {

        u16 bytesAddedToCurrentBuffer = (MAX_SIZE - WriteIndex);
        u16 bytesAddedToNextBuffer = (bufferSize - bytesAddedToCurrentBuffer);

        memcpy(&(buffer_b[WriteIndex]), &buffer_a, bytesAddedToCurrentBuffer);

        // calls another function, process data, resets writer index to 0
        doSomething();

        AddToBuffer(&buffer_a[bytesAddedToCurrentBuffer], bytesAddedToNextBuffer];
    }
}

int main() {
    ...
    u8 buff[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'};
    for (;;) {
         AddToBuffer(buff, 7);
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, the above function works besides the recursive call. I believe I just want to pass in the address of array at index bytesAddedToCurrentBuffer. If I comment out the recursive call it works, if I replace the recursive call with the same logic as the previous if statement's logic (lines 4 and 5), it works great. I want it to be a recursive call so that the function is able to handle a buffer that is way larger than MAX_SIZE.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
WriteIndex starts at 0. It'll obviously increase until it reaches the MAX_SIZE, at which then it'll fall into it's else case, fill up buffer_b, process buffer_b, then start a new buffer with WriteIndex back at 0.

The buffer size that is passed in also doesn't really matter. It could be 2 bytes, it could 10 bytes, it could be 1000 bytes. It'll handle it all the same.

Edit2:
My problem is that the recursive call ends up writing in memory where it's not suppose to and my FPGA locks up.

Edit3:
A more 'complete' example.

Comment: What exactly is the problem or question you're asking?

Comment: Why is this not a plain loop instead?

Comment: Why use `u16` instead of `unsigned int` for consistency with the prototype? buffers tend to be longer than 64KB nowadays.

Comment: `memcpy(&(buffer_b[WriteIndex]), &buffer_a, bufferSize);` is definitely bogus!

Comment: @chqrlie Why do you think so?

Comment: your use of `&buffer_a` is wrong. Remember that `buffer_a` is a pointer (not an array), so you are reading the bytes that form a memory address.

Comment: your question would be improved by a MCVE so we don't have to guess about things like what `buffer_b` is, how big these things are, what the usage is etc.

Comment: still haven't defined `buffer_b`

Comment: Added edit to define buffer_b

Comment: I believe we understand what you expect for a result, but I don't see a proper trace of what actually happens.  Please put that together with the suggestions in chrqlie's answer, edit them into your posting, and get this reopened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code.

- `AddToBuffer` should have a return type.
- You pass `memcpy` the address of the pointer `buffer_a` instead of its value.
- You forget to increment WriteIndex by the size of the chunk you copied
- You use `u16` variables for the chunk size computation, this is inconsistent with the prototype: `unsigned int` may be larger than `u16` and the actual buffer size passed may be larger than 64K. **EDIT** you changed the question, so this point is moot.

Here is a simpler version:

```
void AddToBuffer(u8 buffer_a[], u16 bufferSize) {

    while (WriteIndex + bufferSize >= MAX_SIZE) {
        unsigned int bytesAddedToCurrentBuffer = MAX_SIZE - WriteIndex;

        memcpy(&buffer_b[WriteIndex], buffer_a, bytesAddedToCurrentBuffer);
        writeIndex += bytesAddedToCurrentBuffer;

        // calls another function, process data, resets WriteIndex to 0
        doSomething();

        buffer_a += bytesAddedToCurrentBuffer;
        bufferSize -= bytesAddedToCurrentBuffer;
    }
    memcpy(&buffer_b[WriteIndex], buffer_a, bufferSize);
    WriteIndex += bufferSize;
}
```

If you absolutely insist on writing a recursive function, just fix the 3 problems mentioned:

```
void AddToBuffer(u8 buffer_a[], u16 bufferSize) {

    if ((WriteIndex + bufferSize) <= MAX_SIZE) {
        memcpy(&(buffer_b[WriteIndex]), buffer_a, bufferSize);
        WriteIndex += bufferSize;
    } else {    
        u16 bytesAddedToCurrentBuffer = (MAX_SIZE - WriteIndex);
        u16 bytesAddedToNextBuffer = (bufferSize - bytesAddedToCurrentBuffer);

        memcpy(&(buffer_b[WriteIndex]), buffer_a, bytesAddedToCurrentBuffer);
        WriteIndex += bytesAddedToCurrentBuffer;

        // calls another function, process data, resets writer index to 0
        doSomething();

        AddToBuffer(&buffer_a[bytesAddedToCurrentBuffer], bytesAddedToNextBuffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, I could throw it into a while loop, but I'm looking to do it in a recursive manner.

Comment: I didn't forget to increment the write index.

Comment: @confusedProgrammer:  Why would you want a recursive version when a loop version is trivial?  Are you nostalgic of the lisp era?

Comment: @confusedProgrammer: you certainly did forget to update `WriteIndex` before calling `doSomething();`

Comment: It doesn't need to be updated. During doSomething(), it gets set back to 0 like it says in the comments. By the time doSomething gets called, I know that the WriterIndex is going to be MAX_SIZE. It's pointless to increment.

Comment: @confusedProgrammer:  For `doSomething()` to assume the buffer to be full is risky. If this function is use to flush the buffer to disk, it could never be used to flush a partial buffer, which might be useful at the end of file.  It cannot hurt to update `WriteIndex` and it is a much safer to do so.